# Writing a Python module using C/API and C++ classes

Tags: python, c++, c, module

I am new to the business of writing custom Python modules and I am a bit confused how Capsules work. I use Python 2.7.6 from the system OSX installation and try to use Capsules (as recommended for Python > 2.7) for passing pointers around (before they used PyCObject for that). My code does not work at the moment and I would like to get some insights how things should be handled in principle here. The code should define a class LuscherClm and I want be able to do the following:

```
>>> c40=Luscher(4,0)
>>>
>>> c40(0.12)
>>> <print the result of the evaluation>
```

First question: at the moment I would have to do something like:

```
>>> c40=Luscher.init(4,0)
>>>
>>> c40.eval(0.12)
Segfault
```

My first question is therefore: how do I have to modify the method table to have more operator-style casts instead of the member functions init and eval.

However, my code has other problems and here is the relevant part (the underlying C++ class works smoothly, I use it in production a lot):

The destructor:

```
//destructor
static void clm_destruct(PyObject* capsule){
    void* ptr=PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule,"zetfunc");
    Zetafunc* zetptr=static_cast<Zetafunc*>(ptr);
    delete zetptr;
    return;
}
```

The constructor: it returns the pointer to the capsule. I do not know whether this is correct. Because in this case when I call, clm=LuscherClm.init(l,m), the clm object is a PyCapsule and has no attribute eval so that I cannot call clm.eval(x) on that. How should this be handled?

```
//constructor
static PyObject* clm_init(PyObject* self, PyObject *args){
    //return value
    PyObject* result=NULL;

    //parse variables
    unsigned int lval=0;
    int mval=0;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"li",&lval,&mval)){
        ::std::cout << "Please specify l and m!" << ::std::endl;
        return result;
    }

    //class instance:
    Zetafunc* zetfunc=new Zetafunc(lval,mval);
    instanceCapsule=PyCapsule_New(static_cast<void*>   (zetfunc),"zetfunc",&clm_destruct);
    return instanceCapsule;
}
```

So how is the capsule passed to the evaluate function? the code below is not correct since I have not updated it after moving from CObjects to Capsules. Shall the capsule be a global variable (I do not like that) or how can I pass it to the evaluation function? Or shall I call it on self, but what is self at the moment?

```
//evaluate the function
static PyObject* clm_evaluate(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    //get the PyCObject from the capsule:
    void* tmpzetfunc=PyCapsule_GetPointer(instanceCapsule,"zetfunc");
    if (PyErr_Occurred()){
        std::cerr << "Some Error occured!" << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    Zetafunc* zetfunc=static_cast< Zetafunc* >(tmpzetfunc);
    //parse value:
    double x;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"d",&x)){
        std::cerr << "Specify a number at which you want to evaluate the function" << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    double result=(*zetfunc)(x).re();

    //return the result as a packed function:
    return Py_BuildValue("d",result);
}

//methods
static PyMethodDef LuscherClmMethods[] = {
    {"init",  clm_init, METH_VARARGS, "Initialize clm class!"},
    {"eval", clm_evaluate, METH_VARARGS, "Evaluate the Zeta-Function!"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};
```

Python < 3 initialisation function:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
initLuscherClm(void)
{
    PyObject *m = Py_InitModule("LuscherClm", LuscherClmMethods);
    return;
}
```

Can you explain to me what is wrong and why? I would like to stay away from SWIG or boost if possible, since this module should be easily portable and I want to avoid having to install additional packages every time I want to use it somewhere else. 
Further: what is the overhead produced by the C/API in calling the function? I need to call it an order of O(10^6) times and I would still like it to be fast.

Ok, I am using boost.python now but I get a segfault when I run object.eval(). That is my procedure now:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(threevecd)
{
    class_< threevec<double> >("threevecd",init<double,double,double>());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(LuscherClm)
{
    class_<Zetafunc>("LuscherClm",init<int,int, optional<double,threevec<double>,double,int> >())
    .def("eval",&Zetafunc::operator(),return_value_policy<return_by_value>());
    boost::python::to_python_converter<dcomplex,dcomplex_to_python_object>();
}
```

dcomplex is my own complex number implementation. So I had to write a converter:

```
struct dcomplex_to_python_object
{
    static PyObject* convert(dcomplex const& comp)
    {
        if(fabs(comp.im())<std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()){
            boost::python::object result=boost::python::object(complex<double>(comp.re(),comp.im()));
            return boost::python::incref(result.ptr());
        }
        else{
            return Py_BuildValue("d",comp.re());
        }
    }
};
```

Complex128 is a numpy extension which is not understood by boost. So my questions are:
1) how can I return a complex number as a python datatype (is complex a standard python type?)
2) Why do I get a segfault. My result in my testcase is real so it should default to the else statement. I guess that the pointer runs out of scope and thats it. But even in the if-case (where I take care about ref-increments), it segfaults. Can someone help me with the type conversion issue?

Thanks
Thorsten

Comment: Ok, since I got no response so far and I really do not like the API documentation, I want to use boost.python. However, it seems trickier than I though. That is my whole method now:

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(threevecd)
{
    class_< threevec<double> >("threevecd",init<double,double,double>());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(LuscherClm)
{
    class_<Zetafunc>("LuscherClm",init<int,int, optional<double,threevec<double>,double,int> >())
    .def("eval",&Zetafunc::operator(),return_value_policy<return_by_value>());
    boost::python::to_python_converter<dcomplex,dcomplex_to_python_object>();
}

Comment: In Python, __init__() is invoked after constructing the instance, so that means you can use 'self' without problems, since it is a valid object (although uninitialised) at that point.

Comment: re. calling the instances directly: i guess you'll want to populate the tp_call slot  (__call__() in python).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how can I get around my segfault problem? The ideal case would be to return a complex number in Python.

Comment: Have you tried the `Py_complex` type? https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/complex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The following converter does the job:

```
struct dcomplex_to_python_object
{
    static PyObject* convert(dcomplex const& comp)
    {
        PyObject* result;
        if(std::abs(comp.im())<=std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()){
            result=PyFloat_FromDouble(comp.re());
        }
        else{
            result=PyComplex_FromDoubles(comp.re(),comp.im());
        }
        Py_INCREF(result);
        return result;
    }
};
```

Using this converter and the post by Wouter, I suppose my question is answered. Thanks